# How to get the total sum up until condition, including the row where the condition changes

Tags: r

I'm trying to count the total sum of a column (y) based on a anothe column (x), including the row where the condition changes. Let's say I have this sample :

```
Test = structure(list(x = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1),

               y = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 4, 8, 9, 11, 57, 14, 21, 1)), row.names = c(NA,

                                                                                -13L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

My end goal is something similar to this :

[image]

I found this alternative solution but it works for cumulative sums. It's not exactly what i'm looking for :
[R how to cumulative sums up until condition, including the row where the condition changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64165163/r-how-to-cumulative-sums-up-until-condition-including-the-row-where-the-conditi)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(dplyr)
Test %>% 
  group_by(cu = cumsum(lag(x, default = 0) == 1)) %>% 
  mutate(z = ifelse(x == 1, sum(y), NA)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-cu)

# A tibble: 13 × 3
       x     y     z
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     0     3    NA
 2     0     4    NA
 3     0     5    NA
 4     0     6    NA
 5     0     2    NA
 6     1     4    24
 7     0     8    NA
 8     0     9    NA
 9     1    11    28
10     1    57    57
11     0    14    NA
12     0    21    NA
13     1     1    36
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is exactly what I've been trying to achieve for a moment. 